# How to add a launch condition of searching for a process in a setup project c#?

Tags: c#, installation, outlook, conditional-statements

I have made a setup project for my Outlook Addin in C#(Visual Studio 2010). I want to add a condition to my setup project for Addin which prompts the user to close the outlook if it is open else continues to Install. I'll appreciate any help on this.
Also tell me if somehow we can restart the outlook at finish of installation.

Comment: In the end adding an Installer class to my setup project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you are using VS to create a setup project, but to make it works you have to write a little code blocks and make some settings. Hope these posts will help you how to do that.

[How to: Get an Instance of Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff462097.aspx)

[Extending Visual Studio Setup Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146626/Extending-Visual-Studio-Setup-Project)

[Launching Your Application After Install using Visual Studio 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19560/Launching-Your-Application-After-Install-using-Vis)

Comment: links are helpful regarding setup project but not really a solution to this issue.